# Accessing an object created in another module using python

Tags: python, oop, class, module

How to access an object created in another module using python

Comment: Step 1.  Search.  This  has been asked before.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558979/how-do-python-module-variables-work is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah,

Thats right,

```
from module import desired_object
```

module exapmle:

```
# Desired Module:

desired_object = None
def my_func():
    global desired_object
    desired_object = SomeObject()
```

But make sure the 'my_func' must be called before importing desired_object from your module

Comment: Is your code right if the desired_object was created inside a function?

Answer (score 4):

```
import other_module

other_module.some_object.do_something()
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you could do

```
from module import object
object.function()
```

Comment: Wow, a code listing consisting only of words SO considers reserved.